# React list index is not correct

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing

I'm learning React by making a simple todo list. Loving it so far.

When I delete a todo, it deletes the list item *above* the one clicked to delete. My Index must be off, but I can't find out why.

There is no weird css dis-aligning the rendered delete button for each item. The index just seems to target the item above it.

Code (shortened)

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    let newTodos = this.state.todos;
    let index = newTodos.length;
    if (this.state.input !== "") {
      newTodos.unshift({
        text: this.state.input,
        key: this.state.input
      });
    }
    this.setState({todos: newTodos, input: ""});    
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }

  deleteItem(index) {
    let todoItems = this.state.todos;
    todoItems.splice(index, 1); 

    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems
    });
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-holder">
        <form className="todoInput-holder" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="To do..." value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
        <ul id="todo-list">
          <FlipMove duration={250} easing="ease-out"> 
          {
              this.state.todos.map(todos => {
                return <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" >
                  <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
                  <span onClick={this.deleteItem} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
                </li>;
              })
            } 
            </FlipMove>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Another thing to point out, is you shouldn't manipulate the state directly. In your `deleteItem` method, change the line from `let todoItems = this.state.todos` to `let todoItems = Object.assign({}, this.state.todos);`, which creates a copy of the state as opposed to a reference.

Comment: The mistake I found are: 1. `let newTodos = this.state.todos` will not create a deep copy. So when using `unshift`, you try to change immutable state. 2. You need to provide unique key for the mapping function. If key is same as input, it may not unique, try `(new Date()).getTime()` instead.

Comment: Thanks @FisNaN, I thought I was manipulating my state indirectly by creating a new variable - obviously not. And using the date as a key seems a bit weird to me, but I now see it as the best solution. It's the ultimate unique haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is actually very simple: `onClick` is expecting you to pass in a function with parameter as `event` (see [ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)). So, the place where you are expecting for `index` of `deleteItem(index)` has `event` object placed. JavaScript did secret type conversion in the `splice` call since `event` is not a number, which resulted in the weird behavior you are encountering.

`event => event is an object => convert to valid Number is impossible => event becomes NaN => todos.splice(NaN, 1) => somehow splice treats NaN as 0 always`

To solve the problem, you can change `deleteItem` to take `(index, event)` as 2 parameters (actually, the `event` could be ignored if you are not planning to use it), and you can `bind` ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) the `index` (retrieved through `todos.map(el, index => { ... })`) from the `todos` to it, to circumvent the default `event` parameter.

The following code is runnable, I removed your localStorage code to make it work, you can add them back if you need.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      todos: []
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    let newTodos = this.state.todos;
    let index = newTodos.length;
    if (this.state.input !== "") {
      newTodos.unshift({
        text: this.state.input,
        key: this.state.input
      });
    }
    this.setState({todos: newTodos, input: ""});    
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  deleteItem = (index, e) => {
    let todoItems = this.state.todos;
    todoItems.splice(index, 1); 

    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems // other answers complains about deep copy, but it is not the core issue here
    });
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-holder">
        <form className="todoInput-holder" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="To do..." value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul id="todo-list"> 
          {
              this.state.todos.map((todos, i) => { // i is the index of current todo entry
                return <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" >
                  <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
                  <span onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, i) /* this binds `i` to the first parameter of deleteItem(i, event) */} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
                </li>;
              })
            } 
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of good answers here, I will be making many changes to my code based off all of them, but your comments throughout the code -especially about the deep copy were very informative. I'll be coming back to this post a lot, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually passing the index to the `deleteItem` method.

First, pass the index to the method:

```
          this.state.todos.map((todos, index) => {
            return <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" >
              <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
              <span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
            </li>;
          })
```

Second, don't mutate React's state with methods such as splice. Anything in React's state should be immutable and only ever touched with setState. If you're going to use splice, make sure to do it on a copy of the array, for example

```
  deleteItem(index) {
    // .slice() will make a copy of the array
    let todoItems = this.state.todos.slice();
    todoItems.splice(index, 1); 

    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems
    });
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }
```

However, an even cleaner solution would be to use Array's `filter` method:

```
  deleteItem(index) {
    let todoItems = this.state.todos.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems
    });
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }
```

Or, use whatever property you use for the `key` in React:

```
  this.state.todos.map((todos) => {
    return <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" >
      <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
      <span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(todos.key)} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
    </li>;
  })

  deleteItem(key) {
    let todoItems = this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.key !== key)
    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems
    });
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }
```

Comment: I'll use your suggested techniques for deleting an item for sure for years to come, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here:

```
deleteItem(index) {
    //index is the Event Object here
    let todoItems = this.state.todos;
    todoItems.splice(index, 1); 

    this.setState({
      todos: todoItems
    });
    this.setLocalStorage();
  }

<span onClick={this.deleteItem} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
//Here React pass the event object as parameter to deleteItem
```

so, basically you need to change the way you are calling the function to something like this

```
<span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In render() method, you do not pass the index into the item object

```
this.state.todos.map((todos, index) => 
  <li key={todos.key} className="todo-li-item" >
    <span className="todo-item">{todos.text}</span>
    <span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)} className="delet-todo">&#10005;</span>
  </li>
);
```